# How to balance progress bar dots

Tags: html, css

Any way to ensure that the green line is equal length to the left and between the dots on this line? Even when the browser is resized?

I am not sure what the best way to do it is. I can make the lines the same size but cannot keep the right-hand circle at the end, or just make it look visually balanced.

```css
#wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#item1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  padding: 24px 0px 41px;
}

#item1:after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 120.313px;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#item1:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 120.313px;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#label_wrapper_1 {
  align-self: center;
}

#label_wrapper_1:before {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  content: '✓';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}

#wrapper2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  padding: 24px 0px 41px;
}

#wrapper2:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#label_wrapper_2:before {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  content: '✓';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="item1">
    <div id="label_wrapper_1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="label_wrapper_2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A fiddle for your convenience:

http://jsfiddle.net/ha7uqe9x/3/

Ideally I would like it to look more like this:
[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what your expected layout is. Including a mock-up image would help.

Comment: Mock-up added, thank you!

Comment: Can you just remove the `#item1:after` styles?

Comment: @NateWhittaker Unfortunately, no. In the real project, which this example is just an extract from, removing the #item1:after style equivalent results in some problems. We need to leave the classes as-is and just tweak existing values or possibly add new ones. Thank you for the idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

is this?

```css
#wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position:relative;
}

#item1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  padding: 24px 0px 41px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

#item1:after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 120.313px;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#item1:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 120.313px;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#label_wrapper_1 {
  align-self: center;
}

#label_wrapper_1:before {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  content: '✓';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}

#wrapper2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  padding: 24px 0px 41px;
}

#wrapper2:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#label_wrapper_2:before {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  content: '✓';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  background: rgb(124, 179, 66) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="item1">
    <div id="label_wrapper_1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="label_wrapper_2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and report back. Thank you!

Comment: So it didn't really work that well because there is an opacity to the background (which I omitted from the original post, my bad) which makes simple translation not look that great due to overlapping colours.